# Is the figurative meaning of 걸리다 only used with illnesses?

Tags: word-usage

걸리다 - meaning to be caught or 'hooked' *by* something - is used for illnesses:

> 감기에 걸리다 - to catch a cold
>
> 병에 걸리다 - to get sick

Are there any common usages of this sense of 걸리다 other than with illnesses? Are there any positive usages perhaps?

(I don't mean 걸리다 meaning literally to be hung/hooked, or the version meaning to take a length of time to do something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some other uses of -에 걸리다 with similar senses.  I don't think there are any positive uses though:

- Caught in a trap:

> 덫에 걸리다

- fall under a spell:

> 요술에 걸리다

- weigh on one's mind:

> 마음에 걸리다

Answer (score 3):

> 어제 음주 운전 검문에 걸렸다.

I was caught in a general crackdown on drunk drivers yesterday.
(걸렸다 is the past of 걸리다.)

> 염소가 덫에 걸렸다.

The goat was caught in a trap.